# How to create a ReactJS zoomable image lightbox

Tags: reactjs, mobile, slideshow, responsive

I'm creating a gallery of images in ReactJs. There are a lot of examples online, but i didn't find anything that is perfectly responsive on desktop browsers and also completely mobile friendly.

In particular, when an image is opened on the mobile browser, i need to be able to zoom the photo with a double tap, and close the photo when i drag it to the bottom

I already tried all the principal solution that i found online.
For example, i tried all of these https://reactjsexample.com/tag/lightbox/
and much much more.

I also tried different approaches like CSS rules, Viewport rules, create a simple zoomable html div, etc... But nothing worked.

Basically, what i what to achieve is exactly something like this: https://www.lucapetruzzi.com/gallery/1

Created thanks to this library: https://photoswipe.com/ that unfortunately i can't use in React. 
(I also tried the react-photoswipe and react-photoswipe-2 libraries but it seems not maintained and not working with new versions of React)

Thank you for any help

Comment: maybe you can use *raw (not wrapped by react)* photoswipe, by writing `window.onload` event function handler can init the component?

Comment: Thank you Shiro, honestly i don't know how to do it. You mean to put it on the html page? Isn't it an anti-pattern?

Comment: Include link to `<head>`, add `pswp` in React Component, and initialize in `window.onload`...Yes, this is a quick but anti-pattern solution, or since you have tried the react-photoswipe, you can wrap it by yourself.

Comment: I tried, but i get a mess of errors like: 'define' is not defined' or 'Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for previous comments, I wrote a snippet for you, check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pohtoswipe-raw-qll1c)

Here are the mainly steps:

1. use `npm install photoswipe` so **DON'T** need to include builded js but **NEED** to include css in `index.html` (or you can import in `App.css`)
2. write the markup in js component
3. init it by click `button` or in `useEffect`

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! I'll try to include it in my project and I'll let you know